# android web service client KSOAP vs WSDL2Java

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I've used wsdl2java before to generate stubs, is there any reason why I shouldn't use wsdl2java to generate my stubs for an android app?  I ask because I see a lot of discussion about KSoap with adriod development, however it doesn't seem as nice as generating stubs through wsdl2java.

So should i use wsdl2java to gen stubs for my andriod app?

Answer (score 0):

wsdl2java generates code which relies on JAX-WS. Android does not include an implementation of JAX-WS, so the code that you generate will not work.

Comment: So, have you some suggestion to do that?